# Build Specific Dockerfile from set of dockerfiles in github action

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions, building-github-actions

Consider we Have 10 Docker files but i made some changes only in 1 Docker file.so In Github action we generally build all 10 docker files instead of 1 docker file.
So Is there any way to write conditions such that github actions should build that particular dockerfile which we made changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use this github action:
https://github.com/trilom/file-changes-action

Go over the docs to see how to use it. But basically an example would be similar to this:

```
- name: Get file changes
      id: get_file_changes
      uses: trilom/file-changes-action@v1.2.3
      with:
        githubToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        plaintext: true
    - name: Echo file changes
      run: |
        echo Changed files: ${{ steps.get_file_changes.outputs.files }}
    - name: do something on the changed files ussing ${{ steps.get_file_changes.outputs.files }}
      .
      .
      .
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It is better to have answers with relevant snippets of code, and not only with links (since the links can change or disappear).

Comment: Thanks @J-Mous ...i will try to use above method to get it done

Comment: @adityaDamera let me know if that helps and accept my answer in this case please!!